# Expresión regular para encontrar comas fuera de paréntesis

Tags: javascript, typescript, regex

Estoy tratando de reemplazar todas las comas **,** por una equis, todas a excepción de las que estén dentro de paréntesis (), entonces trato de hacer una expresión regular para lograr este objetivo.

```js
    const regExp = /((?!\(.*,.*\)))/g;
```

Allí trato de decir que NO capture las comas que están dentro de paréntesis,
sin embargo esto parece no funcionar.

Quiero que mi expresión regular actúe de la siguiente manera.

// Aserciones en negrita.

(Pan, leche, queso, mantequilla) tortilla **,** arroz **,** lechuga.

// Aserciones de color rojo y comas ignoradas de color azul.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, las comas que se encuentran dentro de las paréntesis no
deben tomarse en cuenta y las que están afuera, sí.

Answer (score 1):

El Siguiente código sustituye, las comas por "x" exceptuando las de adentro de los paréntesis:

```js
var test =  "(Pan, leche, torta), huevo, queso, frijol";
var regex = /,(?![^()]*\))/g;
var result = test.replace(regex, ' x');
console.log(result);
```